# NoMethodError (undefined method `info' for nil:NilClass) `find_for_google_oauth2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth, google-authentication, nomethoderror

! am trying to allow co-workers and students to sign up using their google project accounts. I have gotten as far as the token being passed but then i get an error.

1. app/models/user.rb:70:in `find_for_google_oauth2'

app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:5:in `create'

my authentication controller create method

```
    def create
       auth = request.env[":google_oauth2"]
       @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
       redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
   end
```

my user model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
       user.last_name = auth.info.last_name   # assuming the user model has a name
       user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
  end
 end

    def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
        data = access_token.info
        user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first


    unless user
        user = User.create(name: data["name"],
             email: data["email"],
             uid: access_token.uid,
             provider: access_token.provider,
             password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            )
          end
          user
        end
```

and my config/omniauth.rd

```
require 'omniauth-google-oauth2'

OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
  OmniAuth.logger.progname = "omniauth"
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do



    provider :google_oauth2, '***********petnk.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        google_client_secret: '***********',
        prompt: "consent",
        select_account: true,
        scope: 'userinfo.email',
        image_aspect_ratio: 'square',
        image_size: 50
        on_failure { |env|AuthenticationsController.action(:failure).call(env) }

    end
```

Not sure what to include to help y'all help me. I am new to rails and have been trying to learn for the past year so any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Any way to check that `access_token` in `self. find_for_google_oauth2` isn't nil?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Good question, not quite sure how i would do that? I now its a little syntax thing, but i can't seem to find it and I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Not sure why i got down voted without and explanation, i would hope this is a community to help and teach, not shame and admonish.

Comment: It'd be good to leave a message everytime one downvotes, unless the reason is so obvious, but I think this isn't the case. Put a `byebug` right after the method definition to check the value, like `def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil); byebug`, this will "stop" the application and you'll be able to check those variables in the same workflow but in your rails server.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma great suggestions, this is what the results were. Processing by AuthenticationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"google_oauth2"=>"google_oauth2"}

[65, 74] ...(i edited this out for brevity)
   66:     end
   67:   end
   68: 
   69:   def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil); byebug
=> 70:     data = access_token.info
   71:     user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first
   72: 
   73:     unless user
   74:     user = User.create(name: data["name"],
(byebug)

Comment: Put the byebug right after the method, [this](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/7599fcbc7db155b8d4094430e010c961) way, when the application makes use of this method, the rails server will "stop", then you can type `access_token` and see what's its value.

Comment: @SebastiánPalmathank you for the clear, concise instructions and the link. I did that and the access_token came back 'nil'. Does that mean it is not properly receiving the token? or storing the token?

Comment: Yes, with that info, and knowing how to debug, you can go back now, and check where you're sending that value from and check why is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move my create function from my authentication controller to my omnicontroller. not really sure why this solved the problem but for now it did.